# Waterfall with two series using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, series, waterfall

I'm trying to set two Waterfall series using Highcharts in the same chart, I have only see one serie in this type of chart in Highcharts samples. I have manipulate the data to be an array but still not working.

I mean two independent waterfall series (one next to each other no-stacked) , like column chart. Like this one (http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/6886/qghm.png)

Comment: Would it be possible to post some of your code and/or a jsFiddle replicating this issue? What part is "still not working"?

Comment: I was able to create on with 2 waterfall series without an issue. http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/kLgsQ/  What in particular isn't working for you?

Comment: I mean two independent waterfall series (one next to each other no-stacked) , like column chart. I trying to make this chart (http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/6263/wq36.png)

Comment: Bug filled here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2321 - thanks!